# jQuery UI Sortable a little quirky in IE. The demo from jQuery UI works fine in Chrome, but it quirky in IE. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my Script...This works fine in Chrome, but the sortable item jumps to the top of the screen when I try to move it in IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() 
{
   $("#sortable tbody.content").sortable({ 
      handle: ".sortablehandle", 
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight" 
   });
   $("#sortable tbody.content").disableSelection();
});

function chkTForm() 
{
   var tString = " ";
   var tArray = $("#sortable tbody.content").sortable("toArray");

   for (var i = 0; i < tArray.length; i++) {
      tString += tArray[i] + " ";
   }
} 
</script>
```

Here is my HTML.  This is a simple abstract of my code.  The code is actually dynamic in reality.

```
<table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' width='100%' id='sortable' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='3'  border='1'>
<tbody class='content'>
<tr id='1'>
   <td class='sortablehandle'>
      <strong>Song 1 Title</strong>
      <blockquote>Song 1 Description</blockquote>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id='2'>
   <td class='sortablehandle'>
      <strong>Song 2 Title</strong>
      <blockquote>Song 2 Description</blockquote>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id='3'>
   <td class='sortablehandle'>
      <strong>Song 3 Title</strong>
      <blockquote>Song 3 Description</blockquote>
   </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What version of IE have you tested with?

Comment: I just tested your code in IE9 using the latest jQuery and it worked fine. The sortable item didn't jump or do anything unexpected.